# Python Windows API retrieve open folders ONLY

Tags: python-3.x, winapi

I'm trying to figure out the best way, using the Windows API, to retrieve the currently open folders on my desktop.  I just want the *folders* I opened myself, such as "downloads", or "my pictures" (or whatever).  The way I've tried is by checking if they are tied to the explorer.exe process, but that doesn't work too well because there are a ton of windows used by that process.  Again, I just want the folders that I opened, not applications that are open and OS related things.  I tried `EnumWindows`, but like I said, that returns a crap load of things.  I looked through some of the API docs, but couldn't find an obvious path to a solution.  Maybe someone here has an idea.

Comment: Don't try to hack through windows and processes. Use the shell API.

Comment: Ok.  I'll take a look at the docs.

Comment: [Querying information from an Explorer window](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040720-00/?p=38393).

Comment: Thanks but that link is dated.  I can't find those functions anywhere in the API docs.

Comment: An article covering the Windows API that was correct 17 years ago is probably still correct today. This one certainly is. Not sure which functions you are having difficulty finding. Start with [CoCreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance).

Comment: Thanks, but I figured out a way to do what I want.  Mostly.  I'd still like to get the path to the handles (folders specifically), but I'm working on that.